# Shopify: Showing a certain breadcrumb on /collections/all

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to display a certain breadcrumb only if the user is on the /collections/all page but am having trouble with which code I use to check that I am on that page. I tried collection.title and collection.handle and collection.url == all and it didn't seem to work. What code can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. To create specific breadcrumb code for the /collections/all page, I used:

{% if collection.handle == "all" %}
        all products
        {% endif %}

(there is other code that creates home >> etc.)